# mutate w for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data that looks like this...

```
df <- tibble (
  old_col = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

... and I am trying to write a for loop that will add a variable that counts incrementally, changing each time there is a TRUE, so I end up with a df like this...

```
df <- tibble (
  old_col = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
new_col = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

So far I have tried this code...

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i==1){
   df$new_col[i]= 1 # For first point
  }
  else if(df$old_col[i] == "FALSE") {
   df$new_col[i]=df$new_col[i-1] 
  }
  
  else {
   df$new_col[i]=2
  }
  
}
```

but the else part is wrong. I don't know what to put to make it count to 3 and then 4 next time there is a TRUE.

I am a loop newbie! thanks for your help!

PS if there is a tidyverse solution to this kind of problem, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take cumulative sum over logical values which will automatically increment for every `TRUE` value. Since the 1st value is `FALSE` we add `+ 1` to the output of `cumsum`.

```
df$new_col <- cumsum(df$old_col) + 1
df

# A tibble: 12 x 2
#   old_col new_col
#   <lgl>     <dbl>
# 1 FALSE         1
# 2 FALSE         1
# 3 FALSE         1
# 4 FALSE         1
# 5 FALSE         1
# 6 TRUE          2
# 7 FALSE         2
# 8 FALSE         2
# 9 FALSE         2
#10 TRUE          3
#11 FALSE         3
#12 FALSE         3
```

Using `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(new_col = cumsum(old_col) + 1)
```

Comment: ahhh of course, you can sum a logical- thats awesome! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`cumsum()` is the standard way to go here. You *could* still use the loop just with minor modifications (I also added some simplifications/cleaning):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    # For first point
    df$new_col[i] = 1
  } else if (!df$old_col[i]) {
    df$new_col[i] = df$new_col[i-1] 
  } else {
    df$new_col[i] = df$new_col[i-1] + 1L
  }
}
```